# submit two different form without reloading

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have two form on one page:

```
<form id="otp" class="w3-container" method="post" action="process.php">
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black"><b>Email</b></label>
<p><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"></p>
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black"><b>Phone</b></label>
<p><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone"></p>
<p class="w3-center"><button class="w3-btn w3-green w3-round" style="width:100%;height:40px" name="btn-save">Send</button></p>
</form>

<h2>Verify</h2>
<br>



<form id="verify" class="w3-container" method="post" action="otp.php">
<br>
<br>
<p><input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="password" placeholder="OTP" name="otpvalue"></p>
<p class="w3-center"><button class="w3-btn w3-green w3-round" style="width:100%;height:40px" name="save">Submit</button></p>
<p class="w3-center"><button class="w3-btn w3-green w3-round" style="width:100%;height:40px" name="resend">Resend</button></p>
</form>
```

I use ajax call to submit these forms to prevent reloading a page, here the ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#otp');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Check Email for OTP');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#verify');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('invalid/Valid');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });


</script>
```

Buut, these two form always called the latest ajax, is there a way to make this form called each ajax based on the form id? Or any better way how to solved this within goal without reloading/refresh the page?

Thanks,

Comment: try changing frm variable name, for example frm1 e frm2, it could be that variables are in the same scope

Comment: Second var overrides the first one. Just name the second one `frm2`.